# How to have variadic templates with a type and a size?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

Just for fun I am trying to overload a `struct`, one for a `std::array<T,SIZE>`, one for a `std::vector<T>`, and a `std::unordered_map<T,U>`. So I did the following:

```
  template<typename... T>
  struct Cont; 

  template<typename T, std::size_t SIZE>
  struct Cont<T,SIZE>
  {
    Cont(std::string n) : name(n){}

    std::string name;
    std::array<T,SIZE> array;
  };

  template<typename T>
  struct Cont<T>
  {
    Cont(std::string n) : name(n){}

    std::string name;
    std::vector<T> vector;
  };

  template<typename T, typename U>
  struct Cont<T,U>
  {
    Cont(std::string n) : name(n){}

    std::string name;
    std::unordered_map<T,U> unordered_map;
  };
```

However, when I try to compile it, I get the error `expected a type, got SIZE`. Which I totally understand is because `typename... T` is expecting a type and not a `std::size_t`. So I tried:

```
template<std::size_t SIZE, typename... T>
struct Cont;

template<typename... T>
struct Cont;
```

Which also doesn't work since I am then redefining and not overloading like I originally thought I was doing. I also realize, that I can do:

```
template<std::size_t SIZE, typename... T>
struct Cont;
```

However I am trying to keep this as clean as possible in the sense when I declare them I want to be able to do:

```
int main()
{
  Cont<int,5> myArray("myArray");
  myArray.array = {1,2,3,4,5};

  Cont<int> myVector("myVector");
  myVector.vector = {1,2,3,4};

  Cont<int,int> myMap("myMap");
  myMap.unordered_map[0] = 2;
}
```

Is there a way to either overload the template? (I assume this is no) or construct a template in a way that says I'm either `typename... T` or `typename T, std::size_t SIZE`?

Comment: The simplest is to declare your template with a size parameter and a default for that parameter. If size is the number of objects, the the default would be size=1. Or a specialisation for size=1, looking closer at your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how to get exactly what you want. Maybe a more clever user has an exact solution. But one alternative might be to just have a type parameter pack for your template and use `std::integral_constant`s for your numeric template arguments. Then you could specialize for each case. For example :

```
#include <array>
#include <type_traits>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>

template<class...>
struct Cont;

template<class T, class U, U S>
struct Cont<T, std::integral_constant<U, S>>
{
    Cont(const char *) {};
    std::array<T, S> array;
};

template<class T>
struct Cont<T>
{
    Cont(const char *) {};
    std::vector<T> vector;
};

template<class T>
struct Cont<T, T>
{
    Cont(const char *) {};
    std::unordered_map<T, T> unordered_map;
};

int main()
{
  Cont<int,std::integral_constant<int, 5>> myArray("myArray");
  myArray.array = {1,2,3,4,5};

  Cont<int> myVector("myVector");
  myVector.vector = {1,2,3,4};

  Cont<int,int> myMap("myMap");
  myMap.unordered_map[0] = 2;
}
```

Comment: It's not pretty, but this does work! How long will it take for me as a programmer to think `std::integral_constant` when I see something like this?

Comment: @Sailanarmo I'm not sure it should be the reflex to think of `std::integral_constant`. It's way *nicer* to just use a `std::size_t` or `int` instead. But I've found that when type arguments and value arguments mix it usually fixes the problem. My recommendation as of now would be to stick with numeric template parameters when you can because it's simply easier to read and understand, not to mention easier to use. There might be a solution with `auto` templates but I haven't had many opportunities to apply them.

Comment: I have never heard of auto templates. I'm going to go look them up!

Answer (score 1):

You could make it be `Cont<std::array<int, 5>>`, and then have a `template<typename T, std::size_t SIZE> struct Cont<std::array<T, SIZE>>;` specialisation, but that breaks the pattern of the other types.

Another thing you can have is, in addition to making `5` into a type by wrapping it in a `std::integral_constant`, make a pair of overloaded helper functions to automatically do it for you:

```
template<typename... T>
Cont<T...> make_cont(std::string name) {
    return { std::move(name) };
}

template<typename T, std::size_t SIZE>
Cont<T, std::integral_constant<std::size_t, SIZE>> make_cont(std::string name) {
    return { std::move(name) };
}

int main() {
    auto myArray = make_cont<int, 5>("myArray");
    myArray.array = {1,2,3,4,5};

    auto myVector = make_cont<int>("myVector");
    myVector.vector = {1,2,3,4};

    auto myMap = make_cont<int, int>("myMap");
    myMap.unordered_map[0] = 2;
}
```

Comment: Gah, I wish I could accept both of your answers! Your added feature makes it look so much cleaner and François' answer is great.

Comment: Can I ask you what `return { std::move(name) };` does?

Comment: @Sailanarmo It creates a `Cont<(template arguments)>` (from the return type) with one argument: `std::move(name)`. Because the function takes `std::string` for the name (Not `const std::string&`), it makes a copy. Instead of making another copy, it "moves" the temporary copy. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move

Comment: Gotcha! What if it was `const std::string&`? Would you just return the name? That seems incorrect since name is a string.

Comment: @Sailanarmo If it was `make_cont (const std::string& name)`, you can't move from it. You would have to return `{ name }` (Those braces call the constructor, which would make a copy of `name` again)

Comment: So would it be more efficient to have the constructor take a constant string by reference? Or is it best to have `std::move` since it moves the temporary copy?

Answer (score 1):

If you declare the array version like this

```
template <typename T, std::size_t SIZE>
struct Cont<std::array<T, SIZE>>
{
  Cont(std::string n) : name(n) {}

  std::string name;
  std::array<T, SIZE> array;
};
```

Then in main you can use it like this:

```
int main() {
  Cont<std::array<int, 5>> myArray("myArray");
  myArray.array = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

  Cont<int> myVector("myVector");
  myVector.vector = {1, 2, 3, 4};

  Cont<int, int> myMap("myMap");
  myMap.unordered_map[0] = 2;

  std::cout << "myArray " << myArray.array[0] << std::endl;
  // myArray 1

  std::cout << "myVector " << myVector.vector[0] << std::endl;
  // myVector 1

  std::cout << "myMap " << myMap.unordered_map[0] << std::endl;
  // myMap 2
}
```

I think this is the functionality you are looking for and it's is clean and readable.

This works because `std::array<int, 5>` names a type that `template <typename... T>` is expecting and it contains the `std::SIZE_T` information you need to define a `std::array`.